# Where is this self.add_error adds the error to?

Tags: python, django, forms

I'm having a hard time trying to figure out the following code:

```
from django import forms
from django.contrib.auth.hashers import check_password

class CheckPasswordForm(forms.Form):
    password = forms.CharField(label='password_check', widget=forms.PasswordInput(
    attrs={'class': 'form-control',}), 
    )
def __init__(self, user, *args, **kwargs):
    super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    self.user = user

def clean(self):
    cleaned_data = super().clean()
    password = cleaned_data.get('password')
    confirm_password = self.user.password
    
    if password:
        if not check_password(password, confirm_password):
            self.add_error('password', 'password is wrong')
```

here, I don't get the `self.add_error('password', 'password is wrong')` part. In the documentation, it says that the `password` here is the `field` in `add_error('field', 'error')`.
So, is the error being added to the password field? or is it being added to the following part?

```
def __init__(self, user, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.user = user
```

because if I have to access this error in the html template, I would have to do something like this,

`{% if password_form.password.errors %}`

and if it means accessing errors from password field, it should mean that the error is added to the password field... but the self.add_error part confuses me

Comment: Have you tried looking at `add_error`'s source code?

Comment: yeah it says `This method allows adding errors to specific fields from within the Form.clean() method, or from outside the form altogether; for instance from a view.`

Comment: but i'm still confused. if it's structured as `self.add_errors()`, shouldn't it be added to the `def __init__`??

Comment: I mean, look at the actual implementation, not documentation. It might be quite revealing sometimes.

Comment: well the codes that I've written above really work, as they are from someone else's code and I've tried it to see if it works. But the meaning of that... the meaning is what I don't get. Anyway, thanks for the comment

Comment: Can you clarify what exactly you are asking? What do you mean by "shouldn't it be added to the def ``__init__``" – should *what* be added to ``__init__``? The method call? The ``pasword`` field? Something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Form `clean` method is responsible for validation of your form  when the data is sent to it

normally it will run validation on all field using  `clean_<fieldname>()` method and if there are errors store them in `fieldname.errors`

As [documented](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/forms/validation/#form-and-field-validation)

> Since the field validation methods have been run by the time clean()
> is called, you also have access to the form’s errors attribute which
> contains all the errors raised by cleaning of individual fields.
>
> Note that any errors raised by your Form.clean() override will not be
> associated with any field in particular. They go into a special
> “field” (called `__all__`)

if you don't want error to end into `__all__` you can attach it to particular field in your case you added it to password

> If you want to attach errors to a specific field in the form, you
> need to call add_error().